# How to use CKEditor in DynamicData project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor, asp.net-dynamic-data

I want to  use CKEditor with DynamicData Web Site. The all examples that I have found are old version of CKEditor.

So How can I integrate CKEditor with asp.net dyamica data web site?

Any help will be greately appreciated.

İY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did was to modify the **MultilineText_Edit.ascx** file + code-behind located in your Dynamic Data */FieldTemplates/* folder as shown below. Note that in my example you would need to reference jQuery and the CKEditor jQuery adapter, the latter most probably located in */ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js*.

The idea is to use the `HiddenField` control with ID="*State*" as carrier for the data. Notice the client-script that is registered in the overridden `OnPreRender(...)`: On any .NET form submission (here triggered by Dynamic Data trying to save, update or the like), the data from the CKEditor is saved to the *State* Hiddenfield, and the data is extraced from the FieldTemplate control from *State* via the overridden `ExtractValues(...)`.

To clarify: the reason for not returning contents of the `TextBox` control, *Editor*, itself, is that this will return the initial contents of the control, discarding CKEditor changes. CKEditor needs to client-side render its markup and stuff to somewhere, and so we do this to the *State* `HiddenField` (doing it to the `TextBox` control itself will mess stuff up, as far as I recall).

One last thing: If you want to keep your **MultilineText_Edit.ascx** for normal non-CKEditor multiline text editing, put the code in a new file instead, e.g. **MultilineHtml_Edit.ascx** and set the UIHint for the property to "*MultilineHtml*" in the metadata class for your partial Linq2SQL class:

```
[UIHint("MultilineHtml")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

**MultilineText_Edit.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" CodeBehind="MultilineText_Edit.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.DynamicData.MultilineText_EditField" %>


<asp:TextBox ID="Editor" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="State" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= Editor.ClientID %>').ckeditor(function () { }, { height: '400px' });
    });
</script>


<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="DDControl DDValidator" ControlToValidate="Editor" Display="Static" Enabled="false" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" CssClass="DDControl DDValidator" ControlToValidate="Editor" Display="Static" Enabled="false" />
<asp:DynamicValidator runat="server" id="DynamicValidator1" CssClass="DDControl DDValidator" ControlToValidate="Editor" Display="Static" />
```

**MultilineText_Edit.ascx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace MyProject.DynamicData
{
    public partial class MultilineText_EditField : System.Web.DynamicData.FieldTemplateUserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Editor.MaxLength = Column.MaxLength;
            Editor.ToolTip = Column.Description;

            SetUpValidator(RequiredFieldValidator1);
            SetUpValidator(RegularExpressionValidator1);
            SetUpValidator(DynamicValidator1);
        }

        public override void DataBind()
        {
            Editor.Text = FieldValueEditString;

            base.DataBind();
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(
                this.GetType(),
                string.Format("kfckpb_{0}", this.ClientID),
                string.Format("$('#{0}').val($('#{1}').val());", State.ClientID, Editor.ClientID)
                );

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }


        protected override void ExtractValues(IOrderedDictionary dictionary)
        {
            dictionary[Column.Name] = ConvertEditedValue(State.Value);
        }

        public override Control DataControl
        {
            get
            {
                return Editor;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## My Tested solution

- Download CKEditor for ASP.NET (ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.2.zip) from http://ckeditor.com/download

  - More info on installing: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Beginners
- Purge ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.2.zip to for example c:\temp\ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.2
- Assuming your MS VisualStudio 2010 WebSite is located here: C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\MyWebSite\
- Copy C:\temp\ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.2_Samples\bin\ -folder to ...\MyWebSite\bin\
- Copy C:\temp\ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.2_Samples\ckeditor\ -folder to  ...\MyWebSite\ckeditor\
- In VisualStudio, add Reference to the CKEditor:

  - In Solution Explorer right-click ...\MyWebSite\ and choose Add Reference :
  - Click Browse -pane, browse to ...\MyWebSite\bin\CKEditor.NET.dll and click OK
- Create these files and save them to  ...\MyWebSite\DynamicData\FieldTemplates\

Comments and suggestions are welcome.

### ...\MyWebSite\DynamicData\FieldTemplates\CKEditor_edit.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="CKEditor_Edit.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Html_EditField" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<CKEditor:CKEditorControl 
    ID="TextBox1"
    Text='<%# FieldValueEditString %>'
    runat="server"
    Width="800"
    PasteFromWordNumberedHeadingToList="True"
    PasteFromWordPromptCleanup="True"
    PasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles="True"
    PasteFromWordRemoveStyles="True"
    Toolbar="[['Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList','BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', '-', 'About'],['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Source'],['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat']]">
</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

### ...\MyWebSite\DynamicData\FieldTemplates\CKEditor_edit.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class Html_EditField : System.Web.DynamicData.FieldTemplateUserControl
{
    //refer http://www.graytechnology.com/Blog/post/Using-a-Rich-Text-Editor-with-Dynamic-Data.aspx for explanation
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void ExtractValues(IOrderedDictionary dictionary)
    {
        dictionary[Column.Name] = ConvertEditedValue(TextBox1.Text);
    }

    public override Control DataControl
    {
        get 
        {
            return TextBox1;
        }
    } 
}
```

### ...\MyWebSite\App_Code\mytable.cs ##

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;

/// <summary>
/// Formatting the mytable -table fields.
/// </summary>

[MetadataType(typeof(mytableMetadata))]
public partial class mytable
{
    // The CKEditor cannot check the length of myfield, and the 
    // DataAnnotations StringLengthAttribute doesn't work with CKEditor,
    // so you have to do a custom check. 
    // 
    // This works as expected only when NOT debugging. 
    // 
    // In debug mode the application will open a window saying 
    // "ValidationException was unhandled by user code",
    // but the message is shown as it is set below in the code. 
    // Hit F5 again, and application will continue OK.
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
    {
        if (this._myfield.Length > 1024)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(
               "Length of myfield must be less than 1025 characters.");
        }    }

public class mytableMetadata
{
    [DisplayFormat(HtmlEncode = false)]  // The field is displayed as HTML, when not edited. 
    [UIHint("CKEditor")]                 // The field is edited with CKEditor. 
    public object myfield { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this._myfield.Length throwing Error from where you are getting the _myfield  can you please explain me i need to know it's urgent